When URL is HTTPS and on windows CMD line, curl 8.x is not returning output with -w parameter, (works in 7.x) am I missing a new parameter?
Since the upgrade to curl 8.x on Windows, curl has stopped returning output variables for intranet websites using HTTPS, I have tested against well known internet sites (e.g. google) and it works as expected.
I have searched extensively online, but have yet to find any root cause. I have also confirmed that using an old version of curl (7.x) works as expected, but I am unable to use the old version going forward. I have not been able confirm if this is an undocumented feature (bug) or a feature.
The issue is the same whether calling directly on the Windows CMD line or via a Windows batch script
curl -V
curl 8.7.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.7.1 Schannel zlib/1.3 WinIDN
Release-Date: 2024-03-27
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ipfs ipns mqtt pop3 pop3s smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Here curl is calling the unsecure (http) URL (Note that the response code (302) can be seen at the bottom)
curl -w "%{response_code}\n" http://www.notarealurl.com
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a[TEXT REMOVED]>here</a></p>
</body></html>
302

Here curl is calling the secure (https) URL (Note that response code is NOT returned as a variable, however it can be seen in the header)
curl -w "%{response_code}\n" "https://www.notarealurl.com"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved.[TEXT REMOVED]</p>
</body></html>


curl 8.8.0 with command curl -w "%{response_code}\n" https://www.google.com/search yielded ...</BODY></HTML>[newline]302 for me.

On my windows built -in version 8.7.1 it works fine

Hi, I have tested against well known websites (like Google) and it does indeed work. However, it is not working for intranet websites. I have been unable to find any explanation.

curl 8.8.0 (Windows: curl -w "%{response_code}\n" http://www.notarealurl.com yields <a href="https://notarealurl.blogspot.com/">Moved Permanently</a>. with code 301 while curl -w "%{response_code}\n" https://www.notarealurl.com -> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate. with code 000

The issue has been resolved with Curl 8.9.1.

The issue has been resolved with Curl 8.9.1
